# MariaDB 5.5.36 ignores foreign key constraint cascading

Tags: mysql, constraints, cascade, mariadb

I ran into a problem with MariaDB 5.5.36 where foreign key constraints are not being enforced or exported with mysqldump. My further investigation showed that these keys are not displayed in "SHOW CREATE TABLE " or even enforced. I am sure there is something wrong with my DDL, but can't figure it out.

I tested the following using regular mysql CLI.

DDL:

```
create table parent(id bigint auto_increment not null, 
name varchar(32), 
primary key (id));

create table child(id bigint auto_increment not null, 
parent_id bigint, name varchar(32), 
primary key (id), 
foreign key fk_parent_id (parent_id) references parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

DML:

```
insert into parent(name) values('P1');
insert into child(parent_id, name) values(1, 'C1');
DELETE from parent;
DROP table parent;
```

I expected the DELETE or DROP statement to result in an error, but it doesn't and child table still contains one row. Moreover, at no point in this test mysqldump or "show create table child" showed foreign key "ON DELETE CASCADE" part.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE parent` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE child`. Sounds like those might be MyISAM tables intstead of InnoDB.

Comment: Michael, you are spot on. I don't know how we ended up with the server running with MyISAM as default engine! I changed default-storage-engine=InnoDB in my.cnf and it fixed the problem I reported. But it was changed back after I restarted the server. I am tracking down what is changing this setting back to MyISAM on server restart...

Comment: I'd check for puppet scripts overwriting your my.cnf.

Comment: Bill, I tracked it down and it was puppet overwriting my.cnf. Nice guess! :)

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Berkowski pointed out the problem was with MyISAM storage engine. Changing it to InnoDB fixed the problem.